# How to combine/merge date then order by ascending in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

How to combine or merge without duplicating or remove the same date data based on the date

```
[
  {date: "05/18/2021"},
  {date: "05/19/2021"},
  {date: "05/20/2021"},
  {date: "05/21/2021"},
  {date: "05/22/2021"},
  {date: "05/10/2021"},
  {date: "05/11/2021"},
  {date: "05/12/2021"},
  {date: "05/13/2021"},
  {date: "05/14/2021"},
  {date: "05/15/2021"},
  {date: "05/03/2021"},
  {date: "05/04/2021"},
  {date: "05/29/2021"},
  {date: "05/17/2021"},
  {date: "05/18/2021"},
  {date: "05/19/2021"},
  {date: "05/20/2021"},
  {date: "05/21/2021"},
  {date: "05/22/2021"},
  {date: "05/10/2021"},
  {date: "05/11/2021"},
  {date: "05/12/2021"},
  {date: "05/13/2021"},
  {date: "05/20/2021"},
  {date: "05/21/2021"},
  {date: "05/22/2021"},
  {date: "05/10/2021"},
  {date: "05/11/2021"},
  {date: "05/12/2021"},
  {date: "05/13/2021"},
  {date: "05/14/2021"},
  {date: "05/15/2021"}
]
```

How to merge the duplicate data and arrange the date order by ascending.

for example

```
[
  {date: "05/03/2021"},
  {date: "05/04/2021"},
  {date: "05/05/2021"},
  {date: "05/06/2021"},
  {date: "05/06/2021"},
  {date: "05/07/2021"},
  {date: "05/31/2021"},
  {date: "05/08/2021"},
  {date: "05/31/2021"},
  {date: "05/24/2021"},
  {date: "05/25/2021"},
  {date: "05/26/2021"}
]
```

to

```
[
  {date: "05/03/2021"},
  {date: "05/04/2021"},
  {date: "05/05/2021"},
  {date: "05/06/2021"},
  {date: "05/07/2021"},
  {date: "05/08/2021"},
  {date: "05/24/2021"},
  {date: "05/25/2021"},
  {date: "05/26/2021"},
  {date: "05/31/2021"}
]
```

What I'm trying to do is the merge the duplicate date and arrange it order by ascending.

Comment: Sounds like you want to do two easily searchable things... 1) [Remove duplicates from an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218999/how-to-remove-all-duplicates-from-an-array-of-objects), and 2) [Sort an array of objects by date property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123953/how-to-sort-an-object-array-by-date-property). Mind you, it would be a lot easier if your date strings were in ISO 8601 format

Comment: Given that OP has to sort the array afterward anyway, it is safe to goes the [`Set` approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44601543/10317684) to remove duplicates

Answer (score 0):

First you have to sort your array with `date`.

```js
a.sort((a, b) => {
  let tmpA = a.date.split('/');
  tmpA = `${tmpA[2]}${tmpA[0]}${tmpA[1]}` // change the format of date to YYYYMMDD

  let tmpB = b.date.split('/');
  tmpB = `${tmpB[2]}${tmpB[0]}${tmpB[1]}` // change the format of date to YYYYMMDD
  return +tmpA - +tmpB
})
```

Then you have to create a `Set` from dates. Read more about them [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

```js
let set = new Set(a.map(itm => itm.date));
```

Finally you have to create your array from the `set`

```js
Array.from(set).map(itm => ({
  date: itm
}))
```

```js
let a = [{ date: "05/18/2021" }, { date: "05/19/2021" }, { date: "05/20/2021" }, { date: "05/21/2021" }, { date: "05/22/2021" }, { date: "05/10/2021" }, { date: "05/11/2021" }, { date: "05/12/2021" }, { date: "05/13/2021" }, { date: "05/14/2021" }, { date: "05/15/2021" }, { date: "05/03/2021" }, { date: "05/04/2021" }, { date: "05/29/2021" }, { date: "05/17/2021" }, { date: "05/18/2021" }, { date: "05/19/2021" }, { date: "05/20/2021" }, { date: "05/21/2021" }, { date: "05/22/2021" }, { date: "05/10/2021" }, { date: "05/11/2021" }, { date: "05/12/2021" }, { date: "05/13/2021" }, { date: "05/20/2021" }, { date: "05/21/2021" }, { date: "05/22/2021" }, { date: "05/10/2021" }, { date: "05/11/2021" }, { date: "05/12/2021" }, { date: "05/13/2021" }, { date: "05/14/2021" }, { date: "05/15/2021" } ];

a = a.sort((a, b) => {
  let tmpA = a.date.split('/');
  tmpA = `${tmpA[2]}${tmpA[0]}${tmpA[1]}` // change the format of date to YYYYMMDD

  let tmpB = b.date.split('/');
  tmpB = `${tmpB[2]}${tmpB[0]}${tmpB[1]}` // change the format of date to YYYYMMDD
  return +tmpA - +tmpB
})

let set = new Set(a.map(itm => itm.date));

let result = Array.from(set).map(itm => ({
  date: itm
}))

console.log(
  result
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that the object structure is like what you provided:

- first, remove duplicate with [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), since Set will allow you to store unique values. Remember to stringify objects before adding to Set, because `{ date: "05/18/2021" }` and `{ date: "05/18/2021" }` are two different object references, but the same primitive string values

> The **`Set`** object lets you store unique values of any type, whether *primitive values* or *object references*.

- sort by date, by converting to Date and getTime

```js
const data = [ { date: "05/18/2021" }, { date: "05/19/2021" }, { date: "05/20/2021" }, { date: "05/21/2021" }, { date: "05/22/2021" }, { date: "05/10/2021" }, { date: "05/11/2021" }, { date: "05/12/2021" }, { date: "05/13/2021" }, { date: "05/14/2021" }, { date: "05/15/2021" }, { date: "05/03/2021" }, { date: "05/04/2021" }, { date: "05/29/2021" }, { date: "05/17/2021" }, { date: "05/18/2021" }, { date: "05/19/2021" }, { date: "05/20/2021" }, { date: "05/21/2021" }, { date: "05/22/2021" }, { date: "05/10/2021" }, { date: "05/11/2021" }, { date: "05/12/2021" }, { date: "05/13/2021" }, { date: "05/20/2021" }, { date: "05/21/2021" }, { date: "05/22/2021" }, { date: "05/10/2021" }, { date: "05/11/2021" }, { date: "05/12/2021" }, { date: "05/13/2021" }, { date: "05/14/2021" }, { date: "05/15/2021" }, ]

const rejectDuplicates = arr => {
  return Array.from(
    arr
      .map(el => JSON.stringify(el))
      .reduce((set, el) => set.add(el), new Set())
  ).map(el => JSON.parse(el))
}

const compareDateFn = ({ date: dateA }, { date: dateB }) => {
  const timeA = new Date(dateA).getTime()
  const timeB = new Date(dateB).getTime()
  return timeA - timeB
}

const res = rejectDuplicates(data).sort(compareDateFn)

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Set` to get unique values and then use `localeCompare` to sort date after converting to `YYYY-MM-DD` format which could be lexicographically sorted.

```js
const input = [ {date: "05/18/2021"}, {date: "05/19/2021"}, {date: "05/20/2021"}, {date: "05/21/2021"}, {date: "05/22/2021"}, {date: "05/10/2021"}, {date: "05/11/2021"}, {date: "05/12/2021"}, {date: "05/13/2021"}, {date: "05/14/2021"}, {date: "05/15/2021"}, {date: "05/03/2021"}, {date: "05/04/2021"}, {date: "05/29/2021"}, {date: "05/17/2021"}, {date: "05/18/2021"}, {date: "05/19/2021"}, {date: "05/20/2021"}, {date: "05/21/2021"}, {date: "05/22/2021"}, {date: "05/10/2021"}, {date: "05/11/2021"}, {date: "05/12/2021"}, {date: "05/13/2021"}, {date: "05/20/2021"}, {date: "05/21/2021"}, {date: "05/22/2021"}, {date: "05/10/2021"}, {date: "05/11/2021"}, {date: "05/12/2021"}, {date: "05/13/2021"}, {date: "05/14/2021"}, {date: "05/15/2021"} ],
      result = [...new Set(input.map(o => o.date))]
                .map(date => ([date, date.replace(/(..)\/(..)\/(....)/, '$3-$1-$2')]))
                .sort((a,b) => a[1].localeCompare(b[1]))
                .map(([date]) => ({date}));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.reduce()` and `Set` to remove duplicate values and apply `Array.sort()` to sort the dates.

```js
const dates = [
  { date: "05/03/2021" },
  { date: "05/04/2021" },
  { date: "05/05/2021" },
  { date: "05/06/2021" },
  { date: "05/06/2021" },
  { date: "05/07/2021" },
  { date: "05/31/2021" },
  { date: "05/08/2021" },
  { date: "05/31/2021" },
  { date: "05/24/2021" },
  { date: "05/25/2021" },
  { date: "05/26/2021" }
];

const removeDuplicateAndSort = (list) => {
  const set = new Set();
  const uniqueItems = list.reduce((finalList, dateObj) => {
    if (!set.has(dateObj.date)) {
      finalList.push(dateObj);
      set.add(dateObj.date);
    }
    return finalList
  }, []);
  return uniqueItems.sort((obj1, obj2) => new Date(obj1.date) - new Date(obj2.date));
}

console.log(removeDuplicateAndSort(dates));
```